# Get Numbers from JTextField as Array for Standard Deviation Calculation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, standard-deviation

I'm new to Java programming and right now I'm making a Calculation app where you can input numbers to one textfield and get the result of Mean, Median, Mode and Standard Deviation.
the problem I'm facing right now is in Standard Deviation part.
I've created a method to calculate the Standard Deviation based on the numbers inputted on the one textfield in app using the code below:

```
static double Q2(ArrayList<Integer> input) {
    Collections.sort(input);

    ArrayList<Double> input2 = new ArrayList<>();
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + input.get(i);
    }

    double mean = sum / input.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        input2.add((Math.pow((input.get(i) - mean), 2)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input2.size(); i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + input2.get(i);
    }

    double mean2 = sum2 / input2.size();

    sd = Math.sqrt(mean2);

    return sd;
}
```

and this is my actionListener code:

```
standardevButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String [] numString = inputField.getText().trim().split(" ");
            outputLabel.setText(getStandarDev(getValueSet(numString)));
        }
```

but the problem I have now is I don't know how to get the numbers inputted in the textfield and show the result of Standard Deviation calculation when I press the Standard Deviation button in app.

[This is the interface of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axA02.png)

below is the code for main method and Standard Deviation:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    TugasMatematika runIt = new TugasMatematika();
}
public static String getStandarDev(double [] nums) 
{

}
```

I've been searching for the answers for this problem quite a while so I'll be really really grateful if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go for mouse-click listener on standard deviation button and use set method to settext the text field for desired answer

Answer (score 0):

This line of code here:

```
String [] numString = inputField.getText().trim().split(" ");
```

Actually gets every space seperated numbers on your textfield. However, these data are in string data type so you would have to parse them one by one to a numerical data type such a double or integer. Let me give you an idea here:

```
for each String variable in my String array
receivingIntegerVariable = Integer.parseInt(stringVariable) or
receivingDoubleVariable = Double.parseDouble(stringVariable)
```

On the other hand, if you would like to display the actual result of computation after button click, try to attach an event listener to the button and have a handling method that would update your JTextField with the result you had with your computation.

```
JTextFieldX.setText(resultGoesHere);
```

EDIT: It seems like you're using a label for display your results. The same concept applies in here.

Comment: for the parse, should I put them on public static String GetStandarDev or inside the actionListener? I'm sorry but I'm confused as to where should I put it even tho I'm kinda get what you mean.

Comment: That depends on you. I suggest you put it on a seperate method instead so you can re-use it anytime you'd like.

Comment: hmm.. so should I make a separate method to get the value stored in String [] numString? can you at least give me the hint how to pass it? because I tried to write down "public static String GetStandardDev (String [] values)" but all I got is error and I'm confused right now.

Comment: public static String [] getStandarDev(String [] values) 
    {
     
    }
this is what I try to do but it shows error on the actionListener part.

Comment: this is what I tried to do public String getStandarDev(String [] values) 
    {
        String [] test = values;
     
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
            a.add(test[i]);
 return Q2(a);
        
     
    }
but it shows error. can you help me somehow to solve this?

Comment: public int[] parseData(String[] data){ int size = data.length; int[] intData = new int[size]; for(int index=0; index<size; index++){ intData[index] = Integer.parseInt(data[index]); } return intData; }

Comment: it show error in this code standardevButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String [] numString = inputField.getText().trim().split(" ");
                        outputLabel.setText(parseData(numString));
                        
            }
when I use your code saying incompatible int[] cannot be converted to String

Comment: can you please help me just for this one? :( I know I'm being asshole here but I've tried many times and it always show errors I have no idea what I'm supposed to do right now.

Comment: this is the code I use now:
 public static String getStandarDev(double [] nums) 
    {
     double total = 0;
        int nminusone = nums.length - 1;
     
     //Total up the numbers.
     for(int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++)
      total += nums[x];
       
        //simpan nilai mean
        
        int meanvalue = (int) (total/nums.length);
        
        int dbtotal = (int) (total * total);
        
     //Return the mean. 
      return ("Standard Deviation: " + " " + nminusone + " " + total + " " + dbtotal);
    }

Comment: all I need is to get the stored numbers in Array from actionListener and multiply each number by its own and total all the numbers. can you pretty please help me with that?